# How to run multiple python function pairs in parallel with different array as input?

Tags: python, arguments, data-analysis, numpy-ndarray

In `f0.py`,I generate a parameter list, then I save them into an shape-`(1000,M,L,N)` array:

```
np.save('../data/seed_S.npy',S)
```

I have to use one element of the above array `S` in another two functions `f1.py` and `f2.py`, I use:

```
S = np.load('../data/seed_S.npy')
array_x = S[0]
```

in both `f1.py` and `f2.py`,

and then I can do the related calculations with `S[0]`.

Similarly, to run the two functions `f1.py` and `f2.py` a second time, I use the second element of `S`:

```
S = np.load('../data/seed_S.npy')
array_x = S[1]
```

in both `f1.py` and `f2.py`,

and then I can do the related calculations with `S[1]`.

and so on.

My **question** is: I want to run the functions `f1.py` and `f2.py` N times (N=1000), I always have to change my functions `f1.py` and `f2.py`. Is it possible to implement the same running *without* changing the functions themselves?  I want run `f1.py`--`f2.py` function pairs 1000 times in parallel. Besides, I also tried to implement the idea without function `f0.py`, but at each run, `f1.py` generate and save the `array_x`, and the corresponding `f2.py` read and use this `array_x`. Which method may be better? Could anyone provide me a suggestion?  Thanks!

I have tried an implementation as follows.

```py
# f1.py
import numpy as np
from modules import *

class system1:
    def __init__(self,N,M,L):
        # store the parameters in the system1 
        self.M = int(M)
        self.L = int(L) 
        self.N = int(N)
        self.S = init_S(M,L,N)
        self.T = 7 
        # The array 
        self.S_traj = np.zeros((self.T, self.M, self.L+1, self.N))

# Main
if __name__=='__main__':
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-M', nargs='?', const=10, type=int, default=10, \
                        help="the number of samples.")
    parser.add_argument('-L', nargs='?', const=5, type=int, default=5, \
                        help="the number of hidden layers.") 
    parser.add_argument('-N', nargs='?', const=8, type=int, default=8, \
                        help="the number of nodes per layer.") 
    args = parser.parse_args()
    M,N,L = args.M, args.N, args.L
    # Preparing parameters for using in f2.py
    parameter_list = np.array([M,L,N])
    # Initilize an instance of system1 
    o = system1(N,M,L)
    #=================================
    #Save the seed for f2.py 
    #=================================
    np.save('../data/para_list.npy', parameter_list)
    np.save('../data/seed_S_M{:d}_L{:d}_N{:d}.npy'.format(M,L,N),o.S)
    # Run some calculation ...
    o.S_traj[0,:,:,:] = o.S # Note that self.S_traj will independent of self.S from now on.
    for index in range(o.T):
        print("Runing f1...")
        print("Done.")
```

```py
# f2.py
import numpy as np
from modules import *

class system2:
    def __init__(self):
        # f2.py accept the same intial configurations as f1.py. 

        # to obtain the basic parameters: M, L, N
        para_list = np.load('../data/para_list.npy')
        M = para_list[0]
        L = para_list[1]
        N = para_list[2]
        # then store these parameters 
        self.M = M 
        self.L = L 
        self.N = N 
        self.T  = 7
        #arrays 
        self.S_traj = np.zeros((self.T, self.M, self.L+1, self.N))
        self.S = np.load('../data/seed_S_M{:d}_L{:d}_N{:d}.npy'.format(self.M,self.L,self.N))
# Main
if __name__=='__main__':
    import argparse
    # Initilize an instance of system2.
    o = system2()
    # run calculation ...
    o.S_traj[0,:,:,:] = o.S 
    for index in range(o.T):
        print("Running f2...")
        print("Done.")
```

and the `modules.py` is:

```py
# modules.py
import numpy as np

# Functions
def init_S(M,L,N):
    S = np.ones((M,L+1,N))
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(L+1):
            S[i,j,:] = generate_coord(N)
    return S
def generate_coord(N):
    """Randomly set the initial coordinates."""
    v = np.ones(N)
    list = [-1,0]
    for i in range(N):
        v[i] = np.random.choice(list)
    return v
```

Comment: When you say functions f1.py and f2.py, how do you actually run them? Is it from the command line with python3 f1.py? Or are they python functions such as `def f1` in the same file?

Comment: I run them independently, like `python3 f1.py`, `python f2.py`. Actually, I want to run many f1.py and f2.py 's simultaneously.

Comment: @Tomer In step 1, run `python f1.py` and `python f2.py` with input array `S[0]`; in step 2, run python f1.py` and `python f2.py` with input array `S[1]`, and so on. I do not want to change the functions `f1.py` and `f2.py`, I am finding a efficent way to feed `S[i]` in each step to f1.py and f2.py.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running them as different files then you need to give them arguments from outside the script. You can do this simply with `sys.argv` or in a more verbose way with the argparse module. For instance if your f1.py has something like:

```py
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
```

Running `python3 f1.py hello` would print `hello`. You will probably want to convert the input to int before using it.

This should allow you to run it in a loop from another script with `subprocess.run`

Comment: Thank you! @Tomer I have tried with `sys.argv`, and give my code in the question. I let `f1.py` generate and _save_ its arguments and `f2.py` read the arguments. But I still have a question: when I want to run many `f1.py` and `f2.py`  pairs togeter (in parallel), How all the `f2.py`s find the right aruguments generated and used in the corresponding `f1.py`. Because in each `f1.py`--`f2.py` function pairs, they use the same arguments.

Comment: You could save them in different locations, depending on the argument you gave it.

Comment: It is a useful suggestion. However, how can I define the location to save the arguments (an array) is still not clear, because I do not known what it is.

Comment: I use the timestamp as the label of a location, and it works.